# Telnet escape character , norwegian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, telnet

Here's me in gnome-terminal, using telnet.

[image]

As it says "Escape character is '^]'

I've no idea which keys to hit, CTRL ] , CTRL Å , CTRL ^ does nothing.

This is the keyboard layout of Norwegian keyboards - which keys do I hit to get
to the telnet escape prompt ?

[image]

Comment: Given your keyboard layout, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> should work, doesn't it?

Comment: That's CTRL ] , so yes it should. It doesn't. CTRL AltGr 9 Enter does work in Fedora and RHEL though

Comment: @nos: I've been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> from a Danish keyboard in gnome-terminal for years and its been working. Now I'm stuck in Windows, where it _doesn't_ work.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up the escape character you want by passing the option  -e " your escapechar"

> -e escapechar -Sets the escape character to escapechar. If no character is supplied, no escape character will be used.  Entering the
>   escape character while connected causes telnet to drop to command
>   mode.

Comment: As mentioned CTRL Å doesn't work (upper case nor lower case)

Comment: What LnxSlck just wrote means that you can start telnet with an option specifying just any kind of escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Using the command `showkey -a` you can check which character sequence a terminal application receives. You can try different key combinations until you find one showing `^]       29 0035 0x1d`.

```
~$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^]       29 0035 0x1d
^D        4 0004 0x04
```

Note: In my case I was looking for a combination for the Czech QWERTY keyboard layout with Windows Terminal. The working one is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ů</kbd>. The key <kbd>ů</kbd> is <kbd>;</kbd> in the US layout. The combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+... do not work at all in Windows Terminal but they work in Mintty / WSLtty.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Terminal does not pass the escape sequence to the telnet session.
The only way is setting a different escape char when starting telnet, or using a different terminal emulation other than the gnome terminal.

Comment: This is not good answer. Provide proof links please. Also explain how to set different escape character.